# When to logout a user?

Tags: user-tracking, protection

I am working on a security project which gives an admin control over certain devices in a company.

When using the web-based product, say the user switches context and opens another tab or skips to another tab, at what time should we log the user out and force re-credentialling to continue working? Given that the environment in which the user is going to be is mostly within the company, I was assuming a time of 5 minutes after which the user gets logged out.

The concern we have is that an unauthorised bystander might use the device and gain access to the company product.

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this question. It all depends on your threat model and risk analysis.

Comment: @M'vy can you share a link on how to do a threat model and risk analysis please

Comment: Why are you focused on tab switching? If the user puts the device down, then a bystander can use the product directly.

Comment: "An admin control over certain devices in a company" — looks like a perfect case for a certificate-based auth, however, with certificates, there's no such thing as "logout".

Comment: This should be defined in your company's security policy based on a risk analysis and/or threat model as pointed out by @M'vy. Have a look at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trade-off between usability and security and therefore there is no "right" answer. However, there are a few guidelines.

[PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/document_library?category=pcidss&document=pci_dss) says 15 minutes at most:

> For a sample of system components, inspect system 
>   configuration settings to verify that system/session idle time out 
>   features have been set to 15 minutes or less.

ASP.NET has a [default timeout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.7.2) of 20 minutes.

For PHP the [default timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) is 24 minutes, but this is almost certainly [by accident](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703363/why-is-the-standard-session-lifetime-24-minutes-1440-seconds/37176824#37176824).

Some web applications (Facebook, Gmail) don't have an idle session timeout at all. If you want an idle timeout, around 15 or 20 minutes seems reasonable.